# Displaying Image Assets to Home Entries

Tags: templating, assets

I am trying to display the assets on entries.

1. I created the assets group.
2. Uploaded the bunch of images to that group.
3. Added assets to the entries.

Now I didn't understood how to write a code in templates/index.html to display those images.

Right now I want to understood how to display one image.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
{% set image = entry.myImageFieldHandle.first() %}
<img src='{{image.getUrl()}}' />
```

Or, if you want a specific image:

```
{% set image = entry.myImageFieldHandle[3] %}
<img src='{{image.getUrl()}}' />
```

Comment: What if I added 2 or more assets in one entry..

Comment: In the same field or separate fields? If in the same field you can use the second code snippet above to get the specific image you need by passing in an index.

Comment: I done like this '<ul class="tools-list">
         
                            <li> <a href="#">{% set image = entry.mojorServicesIcons[2] %}
<img src='{{image.getUrl()}}' /></a></li>
                           </ul>'

Comment: Images are not displaying

Comment: In the same filed I added 2 assets..

Comment: Remember that arrays are 0 indexed, so be sure to do majorServicesIcons[0] and majorServicesIcons[1]. Alternatively, you can do a for loop inside your <ul>.